# Problems with inner join SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, inner-join

Basically i am working with 2 tables, one is the cars and one is comments and i am trying to get the count of approved comments for certain cars + the cars information, but i would like it to be dynamic if i put in the id of the car directly it will work but when i say where id = car id it returns nothing?

This works with "10" it will give me the information + the count of comments

```
SELECT t1.biler_id, t1.biler_navn, COUNT(t2.bilbixen_commentary_status) 
FROM bilbixen_biler t1 
INNER JOIN bilbixen_commentary t2 ON t1.biler_id = t2.bilbixen_commentary_bil
WHERE t1.biler_id = 10
```

The above query will return this in phpmyadmin
[image]

The below query don't work, i am trying to tell it to find everything where t1.id is equal t2.id

```
SELECT t1.biler_id, t1.biler_navn, COUNT(t2.bilbixen_commentary_status) 
FROM bilbixen_biler t1 
INNER JOIN bilbixen_commentary t2 ON t1.biler_id = t2.bilbixen_commentary_bil
WHERE t1.biler_id = t2.bilbixen_commentary_bil
```

The above query will give me this error in phpmyadmin
[image]

I expected it to return all the information for each car with a count of comments for each of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause is useless and you need a `group by` clause since you are using the aggregate function `count`.

```
select t1.biler_id,
    t1.biler_navn,
    COUNT(t2.bilbixen_commentary_status)
from bilbixen_biler t1
left join bilbixen_commentary t2 on t1.biler_id = t2.bilbixen_commentary_bil
group by t1.biler_id,
    t1.biler_navn
```

Comment: This is better, but i still need all the records from t1 which has 0 comments  in t2, because i will output the cards with a "speaking bubble with how many comments related to the car" so if they have no comments in t2 none of their data will be shown so basically no one can see the cars if there is no comment

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 - Then do left join instead. Updated.

Comment: Ohh yeah ofcourse then i dont just get the relations... need coffee, and thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used the aggregate function `COUNT` so you have to group by `t1.biler_id, t1.biler_navn` fields:

```
SELECT t1.biler_id, t1.biler_navn, COUNT(t2.bilbixen_commentary_status) 
FROM bilbixen_biler t1 
INNER JOIN bilbixen_commentary t2 ON t1.biler_id = t2.bilbixen_commentary_bil
GROUP BY t1.biler_id, t1.biler_navn
```